# How to find the AVG per user using a start date and for a specific period of time

Tags: mysql, sql, join

I would like to find out the average purchases per user who joined say in march for 4 months and 6 months. The answer should give me two numbers

**Table 1 (Users) columns:**

```
user_id
date_joined
```

**Table 2 (Purchases) columns:**

```
purchase_id
purchase_amount
purchase_date
user_id
```

My initial code is:

```
SELECT U.USER_ID, AVG(PURCHASES.PURCHASE_AMOUNT)
  FROM USERS U
 INNER JOIN PURCHASES P
    ON U.USER_ID = P.USER_ID
 WHERE P.PURCHASE_DATE >= U.DATE_OF_JOIN AND MONTH(P.purchase_date) = 03
   AND P.PURCHASE_DATE < DATE_ADD(U.DATE_OF_JOIN, INTERVAL 6 MONTH)
 GROUP BY U.USER_ID;
```

the problem is that it gives me the avg per each single user (i have 20 users so its giving me 20 numbers). And this code only includes one interval when i need two but dont know how to include it.

Comment: Adding the `SQL` tag so more people will see your question, and you'll get more answers.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Not sure if I understood well, but you can do it by "unioning" two queries, one for 4 months, the other one for 6 months.

And, if you want a single value per each duration, then you don't need to group by users.

The query should look similar to:

```
SELECT 4 as months, AVG(PURCHASES.PURCHASE_AMOUNT) as average_amount
  FROM USERS U
 INNER JOIN PURCHASES P
    ON U.USER_ID = P.USER_ID
 WHERE P.PURCHASE_DATE >= U.DATE_OF_JOIN AND MONTH(P.purchase_date) = 03
   AND P.PURCHASE_DATE < DATE_ADD(U.DATE_OF_JOIN, INTERVAL 4 MONTH)
union all
SELECT 6 as months, AVG(PURCHASES.PURCHASE_AMOUNT) as average_amount
  FROM USERS U
 INNER JOIN PURCHASES P
    ON U.USER_ID = P.USER_ID
 WHERE P.PURCHASE_DATE >= U.DATE_OF_JOIN AND MONTH(P.purchase_date) = 03
   AND P.PURCHASE_DATE < DATE_ADD(U.DATE_OF_JOIN, INTERVAL 6 MONTH)
 GROUP BY U.USER_ID;
```